# Electric Fields and Electric Potential

Tags: electrostatics

My textbook says that potential always decreases in the direction of the electric field. Let's say there is a positive point charge at the origin. The electric field will point outward and the potential will decrease. Now if I reverse the sign of charge at the origin, I find that the potential is increasing in the direction of the field (as now the field is inward). Can anyone point where I am wrong?

Comment: You forget that the potential also changes sign.

Comment: @my2cts after reversing the sign i get v= -kq/r which tend to decrease in the the +ve x direction even though field is towards -ve

Comment: V increases with distance.

Comment: It *increases* with $r$ by becoming less negative. The *signed* value is what matters, not the absolute value. Just draw a graph and you will see that the curve goes *up* to  zero.

Comment: It’s also important to remember it is defined with respect to a positive test charge.

Comment: Uhh $v=-kq/r$ increases as $r$ increases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***My textbook says that potential always decreases in the direction of the electric field. Let's say there is a positive point charge at the origin. The electric field will point outward and the potential will decrease.***

That is correct. But you need to keep in mind that it is always the potential of a positive charge placed in the field that decreases in the direction of the field. This is because, by convention, the direction of the electric field is the direction of the force that positive charge would experience if placed in the field. If a positive charge is placed in the field created by a positive point charge at the origin and is  free to move, it will experience a repulsive force causing it to move away from the origin, acquiring kinetic energy at the expense of its potential energy in the field. It will lose potential.

***Now if I reverse the sign of charge at the origin, I find that the potential is increasing in the direction of the field (as now the field is inward).***

That is not correct. The potential still decreases in the direction of the field. A positive charge placed in the field will still lose potential in the direction of the field as it will experience an attractive force in the direction of the inward pointing field. It will, once again, loose potential in the direction of the field.

***Can anyone point where I am wrong?***

You may have been thinking that reversing the charge at the origin (making it negative rather than positive) somehow reverses the change in potential in the direction of the field. You need to keep in mind that the direction of the field is always, by convention, the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field. When the field does work on the positive charge (due to either an attractive force of a negative charge at the origin or due to a repulsive force of a positive charge at the origin), there is always a decrease in potential.

Hope this helps.